# recursivity with jquery in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a "simon says" game, the problem is that when this function executes, the condition in the if never become true, even if I click on the buttons that push a value to the array.

```
function start(patron, patronl){
      if (patronl.length<patron.length){
        setTimeout(start,1000,patron, patronl);
      } else {
        patronl=[];
        patron.push(rand(1,4));
        runp(patron);
        start(patron,patronl);
      }
    }
      $("#col4").click(function(){
    patronl.push(4);
  })
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/wGqEga/) is the example code of what I am trying to do

[Here](http://codepen.io/MaxiPawlowski/pen/QKGzJx?editors=1011) is my code

Comment: problem is global vs block scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicitly watching all your buttons, use an [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).  Just specify the parameters the function needs and whenever the button is clicked it will trigger that function

Comment: you mean, this way? "document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){start(patron,patronl)};" idk but my code does nothing